# could not run Apache properly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, xampp

I am facing one issue. I am trying to start the Apache server but its not working as per expected. I am using the following command to start the local server.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

But its giving the below message.

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.23-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Here my problem is while I am trying to run any project inside htdocs its throwing the below error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test/string.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Here I am able to run `localhost/phpmyadmin` but not able to run projects inside the `htdocs` folder. Here I need to also run those projects present inside the `htdocs` folder.

Comment: Aside from your `lampp`installation in `/opt/lampp`, there seems to be a default apache installation. Try `aptitude search apache2`or `apt-cache search apache2`. This one is also listening on port 80/http by default, try `sudo netstat -lp | grep http` to see if this is true. You will find the configuration in `/etc/apache2/`.

Comment: I have checked apache2 is running on `80` no port.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply run this command to terminal

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and after that

```
/opt/lampp/lampp/ start
```

Make sure you give proper permission to htdocs folder.